# Is there any way to using hadolint for multiple dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, shell, gitlab

[Hadolint](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) is an awesome tool for linting Dockerfiles. I am trying
to integrated to my CI but I am dealing with for run over multiple Dockerfiles. Does someone know how the syntax look like? Here is how my dirs appears to:

```
dir1/Dockerfile
dir2/Dockerfile
dir3/foo/Dockerfile
```

in gitlab-ci

```
  stage: hadolint
  image: hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian
  script:
  - mkdir -p reports
  - |
   hadolint dir1/Dockerfile > reports/dir1.json \
   hadolint dir2/Dockerfile > reports/dir2.json \
   hadolint dir3/foo/Dockerfile > reports/dir3.json
```

But the sample above is now working.

Comment: BTW note that if you remove the trailing "\" and fix the indentation, that should work. But if you don't want to hard-code the name of your directories and ensure all Dockerfile are analyzed by default, see the answer I've just suggested.

Comment: Your suggestion is a more generic solution, I have changed and extended corresponding to my needs. Accept your solution.

Comment: BTW note that you may want to add some `set -x` within the bash snippet, if you want a bit more feedback in the logs → `… && set -x && hadolint "$1" …`

Comment: @ErikMD interestingly gitlab ci bash is not working as linux shell. I have no idea why. The command which works on terminal it is not working in CI

Comment: OK @full_steak_developer, that looks like a standard issue that can be workarounded in several ways; I'll try to come with more details in my answer (on tomorrow Friday hopefully!)

Comment: I was expecting that some parameter expansions used in my answer wouldn't work with a mere POSIX shell (implying some code change and/or the installation of `bash` if the underlying image was based on Alpine or so: `apk add --no-cache bash`) but the good news is that the suggested snippet appears to work with `/bin/sh` (replacing `bash` with `sh`). Can you try again?

Comment: As an aside, `hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian` seems to provide `bash` in the image… so I guess you have refactored the configuration to actually use another image (?) :)

Comment: @ErikMD what I mean let say
`echo test >> output.txt && cat output.txt | grep "test"; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "fail" || echo success` the result of this command should be `fail` But when I

`echo test >> output.txt && cat output.txt | grep "foo"; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "fail" || echo success` the result of this command should be `success`
this is not working in gitlab CI. Always getting `fail` back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep all reports separated (one per top-level directory), you may want to rely on some shell snippet?

I mean something like:

```sh
- |
  find . -name Dockerfile -exec \
    sh -c 'src=${1#./} && { set -x && hadolint "$1"; } | tee -a "reports/${src%%/*}.txt"' sh "{}" \;
```

Explanation:

- `find . -name Dockerfile` loops over all Dockerfiles in the current directory;
- `-exec sh -c '…'` runs a subshell for each Dockerfile, setting:

  - `$0 = "sh"` (dummy value)
  - `$1 = "{}"` (the full, relative path of the Dockerfile), `"{}"` and `\;` being directly related to the `find … -exec` pattern;
- `src=${1#./}` trims the path, replacing `./dir1/Dockerfile` with `dir1/Dockerfile`
- `${src%%/*}` extracts the top-level directory name (`dir1/Dockerfile` → `dir1`)
- and `| tee -a …` copies the output, appending `hadolint`'s output to the top-level directory report file, for each parsed Dockerfile (while `> …` should be avoided here for obvious reasons, if you have several Dockerfiles in a single top-level directory).
- I have replaced the `.json` extension with `.txt` as `hadolint` does not seem to output JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

So as far as I found it, `hadolint` runs recursively. So in my case:

```
  - hadolint */Dockerfile > reports/all_reports.json
```

But the problem with this approach is that all reports will be in one file which humper the maintenance and clarity